# How to prevent a QDoubleSpinBox from changing values

Tags: python, pyqt

I've written a GUI for a script that does some geometrical calculations. Certain ranges of values break the computation (e.g. find the intersection of two shapes that don't intersect.) I raise exceptions in those cases. I'd like to prevent the user from adjusting the spinbox value beyond the point where exceptions are raised.

I've tried overwriting the validator method for the QDoubleSpinBox. This works great when I manually enter values with the keyboard. But, it doesn't prevent me from clicking the up and down arrows.

How I can limit the ability of the user to run-up the values outside of the acceptable range?

Note: The actual `some_complicated_function` involves the values from 5 different spinboxes.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

def some_complicated_function(val_a):
    if val_a + 3 < 10:
        return True
    else:
        raise Exception("Giant number!")

class SpinBoxSpecial(QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox):
    def validate(self, value, pos):
#         print float(value)
        try:
            some_complicated_function(float(value))
            print "yup"
            return QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable, QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable
        except:
            print "nope"
            return QtGui.QValidator.Invalid, QtGui.QValidator.Invalid

a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)       
w = QtGui.QMainWindow()
w.resize(320, 100)
w.setWindowTitle("PyQT Python Widget!") 

spinbox = SpinBoxSpecial(w)
spinbox.move(20, 20)
spinbox.CorrectionMode = QtGui.QAbstractSpinBox.CorrectToPreviousValue

w.show() 

sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

**Edit:**
The basic ask is:  I want to call a function when the value of a spinbox changes (via mouse or keyboard). If that function throws an exception, I want the value of the spinbox to revert to what it was.

Comment: [QDoubleSpinBox.setRange](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdoublespinbox.html#setRange).

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro , I'm not looking to just set the range. The range is very dynamic. e.g. range of the first spinbox might be a function of the tan() and cos() and dot products and crossproducts of other values from other spinboxes. I could re-implement that logic, but the exceptions are being generated from another class that I'd like to keep abstracted.

Comment: In that case, you should provide a more realistic example that properly represents the actual problem(s) you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think this does capture what I'm looking for: I want to call a function when the value of a spinbox changes (via mouse or keyboard). If that function throws an exception, I want the value of the spinbox to revert to what it was.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't dynamically set the range on the spinboxes. Or at least, the example in your question doesn't provide any reason.

Comment: You could pretend that I couldn't see the code for `some_complicated_function`.  Say, if it were a static library.  But the reality is: It's easy to poll `some_complicated_function` to see if the values are valid or not. But to get the ranges that are valid given other values is a big inverse problem. Imagine factoring a number: if you give me two numbers, I can tell you their product. But, if you give me the product and tell me to find the factors, it becomes much harder. This is a similar case.

Comment: But you already know the value, because you passed it to the function. So why can't you use this value to *dynamically* set the maximum/minimum of the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to dynamically set the range on a spinbox:

```
class SpinBoxSpecial(QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SpinBoxSpecial, self).__init__(parent)
        self._last = self.value()
        self.valueChanged.connect(self.handleValueChanged)

    def handleValueChanged(self, value):
        try:
            some_complicated_function(float(value))
            print "yup", value
            self._last = value
        except:
            print "nope", value
            if value > self._last:
                self.setMaximum(self._last)
            else:
                self.setMinimum(self._last)
```

**EDIT**:

Just realized the above won't work correctly if a value is typed in directly, because it could fix the min/max too early. So maybe this would be better:

```
    def handleValueChanged(self, value):
        try:
            some_complicated_function(float(value))
            print "yup", value
            self._last = value
        except:
            print "nope", value
            self.setValue(self._last)
```

Comment: Accepted for the edit. Setting max and min is not a solution because the complicated functions aren't necessarily constant or linear (e.g., changing the value of one spin box may change the acceptable values for another spinbox). However, the edit does the trick.

Comment: Though, if there was a way to bind the behaviour of clicking the up and down arrows to the behaviour of changing the text, that would be much preferred.